# Simple jqPlot showing up blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

For some reason, the heading will move to make room for the graph, it looks like there is a graph above it yet the graph itself does not show. I am not sure why this is at all and the jqplot site said this particular example doesn't need plugins.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>PJQuery Chart</title>


<script type = "text/javascript" src = "javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                        
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var plot1 = $.jqplot ("chart1", [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "chart1"style = "margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:300px;          
height:300px;"></div>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realise I forgot the </div> but nothing changes after adding this in.

Comment: in your example you didn't include the jqPlot plugin, are you getting any error? the jqplot site said this particular example doesn't need plugins, but it is talking about jqplot plugins, you still need to include the jqplot plugin for this to work

Comment: I added in the plugins as :

<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jqplot/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>

As described on the site, but they didnt help at all.

Comment: i asked because i didn't see it in your example, would you please update your example exactly with the code you are testing?

Comment: Added in the imports, the formatting went weird but I think its readable?

Comment: its readable, but still have errors, you need to be careful when pasting. I think you forgot to include `jquery.jqplot.min.js` right after the `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`

Comment: Do you mean in the same src line??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went thru your code.

You have not included the main jqPlot JS file - `jquery.jqplot.min.js` (or `jquery.jqplot.js`)

Also, you have made some mistakes in ending the `<script>` tags. The first `<script>` tag doesn't have the ending tag(`<\script>`)

Make sure, the src-path to the `<script>` tags are proper, and that the files exist there.

For me this worked,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>PJQuery Chart</title>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script><!--You have not included this file-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

//Code..
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ("chart1", [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:300px; height:300px;"></div>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure you include the `jquery.jqplot.min.js` first, and then the plugin files(or any other jqPlot files)

Hope it helps.